# (Django) UpdateView query only working sometimes

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a school management app that has a feature to drop a student or teacher from a particular course. The problem is it only works with some users and not others.

In my urls.py, I have the following:

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/drop_session/<int:pk2>', user_views.DropStudentFromSession.as_view(), name='drop_student_session'),
```

Then in my views.py, this is my CBV for dropping a student:

```
class DropStudentFromSession(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
model = Session
template_name = 'users/drop_student_session.html'
fields = []

def test_func(self):
    return True if self.request.user.groups.filter(name='Admin').count() > 0 else False

def handle_no_permission(self):
    return redirect('denied')

def form_valid(self, form):
    course = get_object_or_404(Session, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk2'))
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    user.student.enrolled_courses.remove(course)
    user.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    messages.success(self.request, 'Student withdrawn from session.')
    return reverse('user_profile', kwargs={'pk': user.id})
```

So the in the `form_valid` method, it grabs the user's PK and the session's PK so it can successfully remove it from the student's enrolled courses. But it seemed to only work with my one test user that has a PK=2, but not the others.

What am I missing here?

EDIT, here's the models for Michael Lindsay:

```
class Student(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
enrolled_courses = models.ManyToManyField(Session, blank=True)
student_id_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.last_name}, {self.user.first_name}'
```

And here's the Session model:

```
class Session(models.Model):
course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
course_date_start = models.DateField()
course_date_end = models.DateField()

def session_id(self):
    new_session_date = self.course_date_start.strftime('%Y')
    return f'{new_session_date}{self.course.number}{self.pk}'

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.course.number} - {self.course.title} - {self.session_id()}'
```

Comment: the other users are students enrolled in that course? It is not entirely clear to me why you use an `UpdateView` here. This looks more like a custom `View`, or a `DeleteView` perhaps on the m2m-model.

Comment: Are you able to post the models to show the Course, Student, User relations?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I'm using the UpdateView because I just needed a simple way to display a confirmation. I was afraid that DeleteView would delete the Session chosen, so I didn't want that.

Yes, the students are enrolled in the courses I'm trying to drop them from. I click a Withdraw button with the above url pattern.

Comment: Is there a form_class? I don't see one specified. If its not there, then the `form_valid` wont be called.

Comment: @MichaelLindsay, no there's no form_class since I didn't really need a form, just a confirmation. I understand how unnecessary the UpdateView is, I'm really just needing a view that takes in the two primary keys of user and session and removes it from the user's enrolled courses.

I'll try to play with a "form", so to speak, and see if that helps, but I think I need to switch strategies and try a custom View.

Comment: Look at the redirect view.  It will get the task done, without having to make new view / template. Possibly use the messages framework for success message.

Comment: @MichaelLindsay so am I getting rid of the UpdateView and putting in this redirect view? Is it also just possible to add a function in my User Profile CBV to execute when I click the Withdraw button?

Comment: The RedirectView offers a nice place to organize the code, and it prevents the user from refreshing & re-calling the same remove method

Comment: @MichaelLindsay thank you so much! That worked. Well sort of. The problem is that `pattern_name = user_profile` will only take one argument, the user's PK, but in my `get_redirect_url` method, I need both the user's PK and the session's PK to remove it from the user's enrolled courses. This is throwing an error saying that user_profile is taking an unexpected argument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MichaelLindsay, I used a RedirectView instead so now the code looks like this:

```
class DropSessionStudent(UserPassesTestMixin, RedirectView):
permanent = False
query_string = True
pattern_name = 'user_profile'

def test_func(self):
    return True if self.request.user.groups.filter(name='Admin').count() > 0 else False

def handle_no_permission(self):
    return redirect('denied')

def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    course = get_object_or_404(Session, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk2'))
    user.student.enrolled_courses.remove(course)
    user.save()
    messages.success(self.request, 'Session successfully withdrawn from the student.')
    return reverse('user_profile', kwargs={'pk': user.id})
```

The only downside to this is that a misclick will drop a student or teacher from that class, so I need to add a confirm dialog, but now it's working.